playstore app content rating when not targeting to childrens
my app can be used by anyone including children. but i want to avoid target age group below 13 because of the ad network and policy violations. i included age groups 13+ only. how shall be my content rating questinaire done?
my app doesn't contain any thing that should be not shown to children. it's just ad network which can violate policy violations

i fixed multiple policy violations with unity level play (ironsource + unity ads)
ads are skippable after 5 seconds
set app primarily target to children in ad networks

now i get policy violation of
Your app contains ads that don’t comply with our Families ad format requirements. For example, we don’t allow: Use of ad walls: Your app contains an ad creative that covers the majority of the screen without providing a clear way of dismissing the ad.
so i am thining of excluding childrens to be included

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
